# "Shopping Cart behaviour" for selecting rows in a table?

Tags: tables, selection, multi-selection, batch-actions

I'm currently struggling with the design of a table that would allow the user to select rows/items from a filtered/unfiltered table (probably with a standard checkbox column) and then still keep this selection when the search or filters of the table gets changed.

On top of that "shopping cart" management (add or remove items, or clear the selection), there will be some specific batch actions that can be applied to the selected items; like adding all of them to a group, having those entries deleted (not from the selection, but from the system) and so on.

I considered using a tab that shows a table with the selected rows:

[image]

But that is a no-go, since we already use tabs like this to, for example, separate entries by a specific type (something like "current tasks" from "done tasks").

Right now I'm fiddling with a bar on top of the title row that expands and replaces the "full list" table:

[image]

[image]

I'm not really happy with this, since the position of the bar will probably confuse the users on what they are seeing on the table and how it relates to that bar.

Using the bar on the bottom is also off the table (pun intended), since we use infinite scroll on tables (that can easily have hundreds of entries) and the navigation buttons (like "next-step") already sit on a fixed bar on the bottom of the page.

I think that's it. If anyone can help with examples or ideas, that will be greatly appreciated.

Edit 1: I evolved the "parallel table" idea a bit and I think I'm getting somewhere:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Re "_having those entries deleted (not from the selection, but from the system)_" – What's the point of keeping items in the selected if they are deleted from the _system_ as a whole as I understand it: They are no longer available in the system, e.g. for a later selection.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have a “show selected only (2)” toggle on the top. Works the same as the tab proposed.

Or, if you incorporate column sorting, sorting by selected is another option.

Comment: Yeah, I think showing the number of selected items on the top is the start of the path; but I'm not really for sorting by selected, since our users will be working with tables with hundreds of entries, both selected and unselected. I will make an edit now to show where I'm at on the "parallel table" solution.

Comment: One issue with the collapsible table is (1) the introduction of a new interaction (delete) and (2) the perceived notion duplicate rows. Checkboxes alone are simple because they are selected or unselected. The trash icon implies the user is deleting the item from the database. This might create confusion. As for duplicate rows, the rows in the collapsible table might be perceived as duplicates rather than the same. This is because there are 2 instances of the row in 2 different tables with 2 different formats.

Comment: I think filtering would be fine for your solution. Try to keep the table simple and consistent to avoid confusion. Test with your users to see what they think.

Comment: I agree about the trash can icon. Maybe something "lighter" (like a left pointing arrow) might be better. I didn't want to use the checkbox on this table, since unselecting them would make the row disappear from under the users cursor, which isn't nice.

The filtering is another beast entirely for this solution. You can check the issue on my other question at 

https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/134885/designing-a-rather-challenging-search-filter-query-for-loads-of-possible-paramet

The question here is having a "permanent" selection that stays on regardless of changes to filters.

Comment: The collapsible table is adding needless complexity (trash can icons, arrow icons, duplicate rows, how to move rows, etc).

Comment: Disregard the comment on the row disappearing; it's gonna happen regardless of icon or checkbox

Comment: How do you propose I show the user a row selection that he/she can add or remove entries from (and that doesn't disappear when a new search/filter gets applied)?

Comment: After applying a batch edit, does it create a duplicate of the item (with the edits applied), or does it edit the original item?

Comment: There is no batch edit, but there might be a "merge" option. In this case a new entry is created and the ones used to create it stay the same.

Comment: The scope of the question seems to get larger and more complex. I think having a dedicated "batch action" section could work but don't blend the interface with the listing page. Similar concept as in ecommerce, listing page is to browse, cart page is to edit, keep the table listing and the batch edit screens separate (the user goals are different).

Comment: The actions themselves (like the merge or any other besides "remove entry") are gonna take place on another window, for sure; but the call to get there comes from that little "baloon" with batch action 1, 2, 3 etc.